# What is the mysql function to show 5 most frequent records in a specific time frame? Using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, inner-join

My database tables and fields:

table author

```
AuthorID pk
AuthorFirstName 
AuthorLastName
AuthorNationality
```

table book

```
bookid pk
booktitle
bookauthor fk from author.authorid
genre
```

table borrower

```
borrowid
clientid pk
bookid fk from book.bookid
borrowdate
```

table client

```
clientid fk from borrower.clientid
clientfirstname
clientlastname
clientdob
occupation
```

I am trying to get the First and Last names of the top 5 authors from the books that clients most borrowed during 2017. So I would think that I would select the author first and last name, inner join the author table with the book table focusing on the author id, and then inner joining the book table with the borrower table, focusing on the bookid which could lead to bookauthor and identify the name of the author. I am not sure if I am wrong in this.

So this is what I tried, to get the top 5 most popular authors among all the borrowed books.

```
select Author.AuthorFirstName, Author.AuthorLastName, Borrower.Bookid, Count(Borrower.BorrowId) as numberofborrows 
from Author  
inner join Book 
on  Author.AuthorId = Book.BookAuthor 
inner join Borrower
on Book.BookId = Borrower.BookId
where BorrowDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
limit 5
```

This gives me an error, error code 1140. But I am not sure if this is the correct way.

This is what I tried to get all the author names between the year of 2017, I did not include the code for top 5 authors from the books that were most borrowed:

```
select Author.AuthorFirstName, Author.AuthorLastName 
from Author inner join Book on  Author.AuthorId = Book.BookAuthor 
inner join Borrower on Book.BookId = Borrower.BookId 
where BorrowDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
```

This code did work and gave me the names of the Authors from borrows that ocurred during 2017. How do I mix the between function with a function that could display names of the 5 authors that had most borrows from their written books during 2017?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about bad code 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Apart from any other errors: You need to `GROUP BY Author.AuthorFirstName, Author.AuthorLastName, Borrower.Bookid` to get sets of books you can count the borrows for and then `limit 5` won't be of any use if you don't `ORDER BY numberofborrows DESC`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your working query you of course need to join the book ids to. However in your attempt you simply joined the borrows without any further means; then trying to count the borrow ids, if it *did* work, would yield 1 (one) for any column anyway. What you instead need to do is grouping the results to appropriate sub-sets:

```
GROUP BY Author.AuthorFirstName, Author.AuthorLastName, Book.Bookid
```

Now all books are collected in sub-sets on which you *can* count the `borrower.borrowid`.

However these sets might appear in any order and you might get any first five books; `limit 5` will only be of use if you sort the results by the count of borrows:

```
ORDER BY numberofborrows DESC
```

So the whole query might look as follows (note: untested; if you find a bug, please fix yourself):

```
select
  Author.AuthorFirstName, Author.AuthorLastName, Book.Bookid,
  Count(Borrower.BorrowId) as numberofborrows 
from Author
  inner join Book on Author.AuthorId = Book.BookAuthor 
  inner join Borrower on Book.BookId = Borrower.BookId
where BorrowDate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY Author.AuthorFirstName, Author.AuthorLastName, Book.Bookid
ORDER BY numberofborrows DESC
limit 5
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the explanation. This is the correct answer. I will pay more attention when selecting the appropriate subsets.

Comment: If I wanted to find the LEAST borrowed books, I would change the order from descending to ascending, correct?

Comment: @SasuKev Indeed, you would ;)